# Error in Serving media images with Django

Tags: python, django

Problem - When trying to fetch an image leads to 404 error
[image: 404 error when fetching image file]

URL Declarations -

```
from django.urls import include, path

from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from my_awesome_api.views import PersonViewSet, SpeciesViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'people', PersonViewSet)
router.register(r'species', SpeciesViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
]
urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
print('avail url patterns')
print(urlpatterns)
```

VIEW DECLARATION -

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework import permissions

from my_awesome_api.serializers import PersonSerializer, SpeciesSerializer
from my_awesome_api.models import Person, Species

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Person.objects.all()
   serializer_class = PersonSerializer
   parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
   #permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()


class SpeciesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Species.objects.all()
   serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer
   parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
   #permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

MODEL DECLARATION -

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Species(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   classification = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   image_url = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)


class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   eye_color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   species = models.ForeignKey(Species, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   image_url = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

SETTING DECLARATION

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
print(MEDIA_ROOT)
print('value of media root')

# URL used to access the media
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

In an effort to troubleshoot the problem, I printed out the media root path and it is correct

/Users/ss1/Desktop/drf/media
value of media root

Printing out the URLs give the output -

[<URLResolver  (None:None) ''>, <URLPattern '^media/(?P.*)$'>]

Here is the URL from PROJECT

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('star-wars/', include('my_awesome_api.urls')),
]
```

HERE IS THE URL FROM APP

```
from django.urls import include, path

from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from my_awesome_api.views import PersonViewSet, SpeciesViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'people', PersonViewSet)
router.register(r'species', SpeciesViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
]
urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
print('avail url patterns')
print(urlpatterns)
```

Here is the screenshot confirming successful image uploads --

[image: successful image uploads]

What did I miss here ?

Comment: Can you share your app's urls.py?

Comment: @SunderamDubey, I have added the URL settings from both project and app to the post,

Comment: Are the images successfully uploading in `media`  folder?

Comment: yes they are... please see screenshot in the post confirming the same

Comment: Go to the django admin panel and click on there, see the image is shown or not? Maybe the problem is with the url as you didn't specify `upload_to` so it stores in the format like `<media>/<app_label>/<model_name>/<filename>` so you'd get a clue by checking on the admin site itself that what url is being used when you click on `image_url` field in any of the models in admin.

Comment: So I made a couple of adjustments as per your recommendation --
1. added the upload_to parameter to models   

image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_files',blank=True, null=True)

2. registered the model with admin.py and found the url of image from a newly created record. i see no change

3. the folder structure now looks to be as -
media--image_files, so appropriately i changed the settings.py media root as follows 
# Actual directory user files go to
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media/image_files/')